# 403 error while trying to list users from google workspace over Service account

Tags: go, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-go-client

```
func (s *Sync) GetGoogleAccounts() error {
    ctx := context.Background()

    creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(ctx, []byte(s.GoogleApiToken),
        admin.AdminDirectoryUserScope,
        admin.AdminDirectoryGroupScope,
        admin.AdminDirectoryUserschemaScope,
        admin.AdminDirectoryGroupMemberScope,
        admin.AdminDirectoryDomainScope,
        admin.AdminDirectoryCustomerScope,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    if creds == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to retrieve directory Client")
    }

    service, err := admin.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentials(creds))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to retrieve directory Client %v", err)
    }
    if service == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to retrieve directory Client")
    }
    cus, err := service.Customers.Get(s.CustomerID).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to retrieve directory Client %v", err)
    }
    s.L.Info().Str("name", cus.Id).Msg("Found customer")
    userList, err := service.Users.List().ViewType("domain_public").Customer(s.CustomerID).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to retrieve users in domain: %v", err)
    }
    for _, user := range userList.Users {
        s.L.Info().Str("email", user.PrimaryEmail).Msg("Found user")
    }
    return nil
}
```

I dont know whats wrong here, i went through all the trouble shooting steps i could find. What i did:

- Create new service account under our company domain, give it admin access
- the user it was created it has access to all domains
- added the required scopes to the service account under domain wide delegation

The code returns the follwing:

```
2023-08-27 20:37:40 INF Found customer name=**hidden**
2023-08-27 20:37:41 ERR Error getting users error="Unable to retrieve users in domain: googleapi: Error 403: Not Authorized to access this resource/api, forbidden"
```

It gets the customer ID correctly but no matter what i do it cant access the user list. What am i missing here?

Comment: You need to delegate to a user on the domain that has access.